# Tomcat upgrade from v6.0.29 to 6.0.37 requirement

Tags: tomcat

There is not much to say in apache's document on how to migration from one version to another within V6, should I simply replace all files? (Redhat 64bit)

http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-6.html#Upgrading_6.0.x

Comment: It's pretty plain in the docs...just replace files and adjust the configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I install tomcat to a directory like:

/opt/java/apache/apache-tomcat-6.0.29

and then create a symbolic link to it:

ln -s apache-tomcat-6.0.29 tomcat

When you want to upgrade, install the new version to the same directory, i.e.:

/opt/java/apache/apache-tomcat-6.0.37

And apply all your configuration to the new tomcat version like server.xml, catalina.sh, jar files in the tomcat lib directory, etc. (essentially everything that you have documented in your changelogs).

Then unlink the old symbolic link and create a new one to point to the latest version and restart tomcat (after deploying your webapps).

You can see if there are any material changes in the configuration files themselves between versions by using the little utility they provide in the link you mentioned.

HTH